# CSS selector to style only the first level of td's inside a table

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>` inside another and I need to set the color to red  for the first level of `<td>`'s only.

```css
.myTable tr td {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Red, please</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>No red, thanks</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried

```
.myTable > tr > td {
  color: red;
}
```

But then, nothing become red.

What I'm doing wrong?
Since I can't include jQuery or any other external lib, I need a solution in **CSS**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try '.myTable tr td:first { ... }'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.myTable > tbody > tr > td {
  color: red;
}
td > table {
    color: initial;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Red, please</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table><tr><td>No red, thanks</td></tr></table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Even though you didn't include the `tbody` element in your HTML, it's created automatically in the DOM, so you need to include it in the selector.

You need the additional `td > table` selector to turn off the color in the inner table. Otherwise, it will inherit the color from the `td` that it's inside.

Comment: He's only trying to target the first row.  This CSS will apply to every row.

Comment: he said first level, not first row. He doesn't want to target a nested table, no matter what row it's in.

Comment: Aha!  You are correct - I'll delete my answer since I misread the question.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Apparently my problem was only the lack of a `tbody`. Are you sure it is really necessary add `td > table`? The cell inherited the default color of my page and not of the parent `<td>` like you said it would.

Comment: The parent `<td>` will be red because it matches `.myTable > tbody > tr > td`, so without that the inner table will inherit the red color. If you have other CSS that gives that `<td>` a different color, then you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr:nth-child(1){background:red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scott88/c6wq3La9/

Answer (score 0):

```
.myTable {
  color: red;
}

.myTable table {
  color: initial;
}
```

Shorter and uses the cascade a little better, like CSS is intended to be used ;-)

Live example: http://codepen.io/TheDutchCoder/pen/zxYRXO